# Draw text over sphere in libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I am trying libgdx for rendering some fbx models and I successfully did that, but I am stuck at a point.

I am rendering a basketball fbx file with the help of ModelInstance and now I want to draw a text on that basketball. I am able to draw text on the basketball but its linear which is not looking as a part of that basketball.
I want the text in the same curve manner as that ball.

This is how I am drawing text--

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/Lato-Bold.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 30;
    parameter.color = com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE;
    parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear; // used for resizing quality
    parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
    generator.scaleForPixelHeight(3);

    BitmapFont aFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    aFont.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

aFont.draw(batch, options.get(i), aBound.getCenterX(), aBound.getCenterY() + textHeight / 2);
```

Where aBound --> BoundingBox of Model (i.e. BasketBall)

Comment: You are drawing text as a separate entity on same matrix. One way you can achieve this to draw text on texture bitmap that you are using for basketBall etc. It will take spherical shape.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve here is slightly complex in libGdx. Your approach, however is incorrect because you are drawing the text as a separate sprite object on top of your ball.

The correct procedure to achieve this is to draw the text onto a texture and then map and bind the texture to the ball.

The procedure can be divided into 4 parts -

1. Setting up the font generation and the framebuffer object
2. Setting up the sprite batch
3. Drawing text, mapping the texture to the model
4. Rendering the model

As a note, I'd like to mention that any other texture can be used and if you do not want to update the text in real-time, you can easily use a pre-made texture with whatever text that you'd like.

The code is as follows -

**Setting up font generation and framebuffer object**

```
//Create a new SpriteBatch object
batch = new SpriteBatch();

//Generate font
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new 
FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/Lato-Bold.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new 
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 30;
parameter.color = com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.WHITE;
parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear; // used for resizing quality
parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
generator.scaleForPixelHeight(10);

//Get bitmap font
BitmapFont aFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
aFont.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, 
Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

//Generate new framebuffer object of 128x128 px. This will be our texture
FrameBuffer lFb = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA4444,128,128,false);
```

**Setting up the sprite batch**

```
//Set the correct resolution for drawing to the framebuffer
lFb.begin();
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,128,128);
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);

Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Matrix4 lm = new Matrix4();
//Set the correct projection for the sprite batch
lm.setToOrtho2D(0,0,128,128);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(lm);
```

**Finally draw the text onto the texture**

```
batch.begin();
aFont.draw(batch,"Goal!",64,64);
batch.end();
lFb.end();
```

**Map the texture to the model**

```
//Generate the material to be applied to the ball
//Notice here how we use the FBO's texture as the material base
Material lMaterial = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(lFb.getColorBufferTexture()));

//Since I do not have a sphere model, I'll just create one with the newly 
//generated material        
ballModel = mb.createSphere(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,8,8,lMaterial,
 VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);

//Finally instantiate an object of the model 
ballInstance = new ModelInstance(ballModel);
```

**Render the model**

```
mBatch.begin(mCamera);
mBatch.render(ballInstance);
mBatch.end();
//Rotate the ball along the y-axis
ballInstance.transform.rotate(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.5f);
```

**Result** -

[image: Render text to sphere libGDX]